# Is there a way to "Pan Behind (Anchor Point)", but with the "Transform Effect"'s anchor point?

Tags: after-effects

I need to skew an image, so I am using a Transform Effect rather than the regular layer's Transform. I'm finding difficult to position the skewing origin without the Pan Behind tool, as that changes the layer's regular Transform, not the Transform Effect. Is there a way to have the tool to change that instead?

Answer (score 0):

In the transform effect, pickwhip the position property to the anchor point property within the same transform effect. You can then move the anchor point using the regular selection tool without repositioning the layer.

[image]